# Using Vert.x Web Client to send GET requests properly with headers

Tags: java, http, http-headers, vert.x, web-client

I have an internal endpoint that I am trying to send `GET` requests to with Vert.x Web Client with Java. So far, I am unable to successfully get any data back.

If I cURL the endpoint, it works just fine (these are internal endpoints). The service I am trying to send `GET` requests to requires a few headers , and data as well:

```
curl -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "alpha:192.168.10.20" -d '{"mutate":"*"}' http://my-endpoint.com/api/get-items
```

But if I try to use this in one of my router endpoints in Vert.x, I get an error:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx);
    webClient.get("http://my-endpoint.com/api/get-items")
        .putHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .putHeader("alpha", "192.168.10.20")
        .sendJsonObject(new JsonObject().put("mutate", "*"), ar -> { 
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("##### WEBCLIENT #####");
                System.out.println(ar);
            } else {
                System.out.println("CAUSE: " + ar.cause().getMessage());

            }
    });
```

The error message I get from the else statement is:

```
CAUSE: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:80
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been using this for reference: [Vert.x Web Client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/)

===========================================

**SOLUTION**

===========================================

I had to change

```
webClient.get("http://my-endpoint.com/api/get-items")
```

to

```
webClient.post(80, "my-endpoint.com", "/api/get-items")
```

Also had to add `.as(BodyCodec.jsonArray())` underneath the above line because the result I was getting was a Json Array.

Comment: Why did you had to change your HTTP method from `GET` to `POST` ? This seems pretty weird

Comment: Specific to the API I was using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
webClient.get("http://my-endpoint.com/api/get-items")
```

to

```
webClient.get(80, "my-endpoint.com", "/api/get-items")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getAbs method if you don't want to parse the url yourself.

```
webClient.getAbs("http://my-endpoint.com/api/get-items")
```

This also applies to any request method, `postAbs`, `putAbs`, etc.